# How to upload several images with WordPress Gutenberg MediaUpload?

Tags: wordpress-gutenberg

I am using MediaUpload to allow the user to upload his / her images. 
However I would like to know how can I set it up to allow the user to upload several imagens.

I would like to make this code dynamic.
I don't feel like copying and pasting parts of the code to allow the user to upload more than one image.

Comment: To upload several images or to select several images? The MediaUpload modal has always allowed you to upload several files.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, nevertheless you can only choose one image when you select it on WordPress backend editor.

Comment: There's a "multiple" attribute that you can use add to MediaUpload (https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/master/packages/editor/src/components/media-upload#multiple) is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks, that did help me in trying to get where I want to - cheers!